# Blooming Problems 5

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Some European types are seen for teas with a taste

The Moroccan variety may sound heterogeneous with haste

Americans add the extra letter for once, pretty strange

I'm an apple of the Earth, but not in potato range

Name the plant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

> chamomile

because

> Chamomile can be used to make tea. The British spelling does not have an 'h'. It's name means 'earth apple'.

Comment: This is correct